# onsubmit not taking the function return value. and not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>

<head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    flag = true;
    function myf() {

        var numbersString = "1,2,3,4,5,6";
        var data = $('#valueHolderId').html().split(",");

        var s = $("<select style=\"margin-left:30px;padding-right:40px;\" id=\"selectId\" name=\"selectName\" />");
        for ( var val in data) {
            $("<option />", {
                value : val,
                text : data[val]
            }).appendTo(s);
        }

        var numbersString = "100,200,300,400,5,6";
        var data = numbersString.split(",");

        var s1 = $("<select style=\"margin-left:30px;padding-right:40px;\" id=\"selectId1\" name=\"selectName1\" />");
        for ( var val in data) {
            $("<option />", {
                value : val,
                text : data[val]
            }).appendTo(s1);
        }

        var t = $("<div style=\"margin-top:10px;\"/>");
        s.appendTo("#msj_form");
        s1.appendTo("#msj_form");
        t.appendTo("#msj_form");
        submit();

    }

    function submit() {
        if (flag) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

    }

    function go() {
        flag = false;
        alert(falg);

    }
</script>


</head>

<body>

    <form id="msj_form" action="winners" onsubmit="return submit()">

        <button id="add" value="add" onclick="myf()">ADD</button>



        <button name="button" onclick="go()">SubmitDadta</button>

    </form>

</body>




</html>
```

onsubmit  not taking the function return value. and not behaving as expected
onsubmit  not taking the function return value. and not behaving as expected
onsubmit  not taking the function return value. and not behaving as expected

Comment: you want the form to be submitted when you click the 'ADD'?What is the use of 'SubmitDadta' button?

Comment: not a solution but in `go()` you are using `falg` in alert instead of `flag`

Comment: when i click ADD some dynamic selec boxes will added to form and form shdnt submit at that tym.. and on click of SubmitDadta from shd submit

Comment: ok, what is the use of flag? its set to true when you click 'ADD' and to false in go() ? what is the logic of setting the flag?

Comment: onsubmit is called every time so setting false / true

Comment: Everytime?How is that? Only when user clicks on 'SubmitDadta' button right? need clarity of your need. what is the logic for the code- if (flag) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

Comment: when user clicks on add..dynamic selects shd keep on adding..so that tym i dnt want submission happens...after that i need to submit all dynamical values by clickng SubmitDadta  on so i can read values in servlet

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're not returning the value in myf()

Try this:

```
function myf() {

        var numbersString = "1,2,3,4,5,6";
        var data = $('#valueHolderId').html().split(",");

        var s = $("<select style=\"margin-left:30px;padding-right:40px;\" id=\"selectId\" name=\"selectName\" />");
        for ( var val in data) {
            $("<option />", {
                value : val,
                text : data[val]
            }).appendTo(s);
        }

        var numbersString = "100,200,300,400,5,6";
        var data = numbersString.split(",");

        var s1 = $("<select style=\"margin-left:30px;padding-right:40px;\" id=\"selectId1\" name=\"selectName1\" />");
        for ( var val in data) {
            $("<option />", {
                value : val,
                text : data[val]
            }).appendTo(s1);
        }

        var t = $("<div style=\"margin-top:10px;\"/>");
        s.appendTo("#msj_form");
        s1.appendTo("#msj_form");
        t.appendTo("#msj_form");
        return submit();

    }
```

And in submit function:

```
function submit(evt) {
        if (flag) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

    }
```

You also must ensure you can read the flag var in submit function.
Hope it helps

Comment: No Luck..still page is navigating....it is return false then it shouldnt navigate

Comment: Nopes...while i click add it shdnt submit.. while i click SubmitDadta it shd submit...its not working

Comment: but how can "add" button submit? it's a simple button and there isn't code in myf function that submits the form.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<html>

<head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    var flag = false;
    function myf() {

        var numbersString = "1,2,3,4,5,6";
        var data = $('#valueHolderId').html().split(",");

        var s = $("<select style=\"margin-left:30px;padding-right:40px;\" id=\"selectId\" name=\"selectName\" />");
        for ( var val in data) {
            $("<option />", {
                value : val,
                text : data[val]
            }).appendTo(s);
        }

        var numbersString = "100,200,300,400,5,6";
        var data = numbersString.split(",");

        var s1 = $("<select style=\"margin-left:30px;padding-right:40px;\" id=\"selectId1\" name=\"selectName1\" />");
        for ( var val in data) {
            $("<option />", {
                value : val,
                text : data[val]
            }).appendTo(s1);
        }

        var t = $("<div style=\"margin-top:10px;\"/>");
        s.appendTo("#msj_form");
        s1.appendTo("#msj_form");
        t.appendTo("#msj_form");
        var flag = true;

    }

    function go()
    {
        if (flag) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
</script>


</head>

<body>

    <form id="msj_form" action="winners">
        <button id="add" value="add" onclick="myf()">ADD</button>
        <button name="submit" onclick="return go()">SubmitDadta</button>
    </form>

</body>




</html>
```